# In ToolbarAndroid - Image could not found from path - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native.

I am trying to show png image in ToolbarAndroid.

I have given path for image is **./images/app_logo.png**

And my Home file location is **./src/component/Module/Home.js**

But it shows error like :

> The module './images/app_logo.png' could not found from
>   'home/admin1/MyFirstDemo/src/component/Module/Home.js'.

I have looked into possible solutions but not resolving my error and I have also written correct path for image. So what am I doing wrong?

```
'use strict';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        Platform,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        Alert,
        Button,
        TextInput,
        TouchableOpacity,
        ToastAndroid,
        ScrollView,
        ToolbarAndroid,
        Image
    } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component<{}> {

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

onActionSelected(position) {
    if (position === 0) { // index of 'Settings'
      this.showSettings();
    }
  }

showSettings(){
    ToastAndroid.show('Setting clicked',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
}

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <ToolbarAndroid
                    style = {styles.toolbar}
                    logo={require('./images/app_logo.png')}
                    title="RNDApp"
                    actions={[{ title: 'Settings', icon: require('./images/app_logo.png'), show: 'always' }]}
                    onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
                    </View>
        );
    }
}                

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar : {
        backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
        height: 56,
    },
});
```

**Error Screenshots :**

[image: Error SS 1]
[image: Error SS 2]
[image: Error SS 3]

### Update

No, my src folder and images folder is not on same level.

Project structure is like this:

```
-images(folder)/app_logo.png
-src/components/Modules/Home.js
-App.js
-Android
-ios
```

Comment: is your `src` folder at the same level with `images` folder? How is your project structured?

Comment: @bennygenel, no, it is not on same level, And i have added project structure in my question in update: section.

Comment: Your paths should be relative to the file you are calling the require function. Try `require('../../../images/app_logo.png')`

Comment: The image path should be `relative` to your `current file` path.

Comment: @bennygenel , Pritish Vaidya  - I have inserted app_logo.png inside src/component/Module folder , where my Home.js is located, But It still throws same error.

Comment: Still wrong path

Comment: @bennygenel ,  Can you please elaborate?? Bcuz, My image folder is now inside component folder, so My Home.js is inside /src/component/Module Folder and app_logo.png is inside /src/component/images. And I also tried to run after putting image foldeer inside Module Folder. And Both ways it is throwing error

Comment: Put your image (not the folder. Image file itself) in to the same folder with the Home.js file. Then use `require('./app_logo.png')`. See if its going to work.

Comment: if you are sure that you give the source path correct. Try restarting the development server and check it

Comment: @bennygenel, yes it worked... thank you very much...  :) this silly mistake has taken 3 hours...

Comment: @zephyr do some research about paths and project structure on google. Problem was fully related with wrong given path.

Comment: @bennygenel, Sure... , I will do it, thank you.